# Access properties of the superclass object in sparql

Tags: inheritance, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to obtain a property that is on a superclass for an object I have found.

I have a list of universities found by [this query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?University%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aUniversity.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?University%20dbpedia-owl%3acampus%20?campus.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20?University%20LIMIT%2010):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?University a dbpedia-owl:University.
    ?University dbpedia-owl:campus ?campus.
}
ORDER BY ?University LIMIT 10
```

I'm aware that University is a subclass of EducationalInstitution from these:

- http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/University
- http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/EducationalInstitution

`University` contains the property `campus`, which is interesting, but `EducationalInstitution` contains the property `locationCity`, which I really want.

While I can grab the attribute `campus` that is directly a property of `University`, when I try to obtain the property `locationCity`, which lives on the parent class of `EducationalInstitution`, I get [no results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?University%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aUniversity.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?University%20dbpedia-owl%3alocationCity%20?loc%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20?University%20LIMIT%2010).

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?University a dbpedia-owl:University.
    ?University dbpedia-owl:locationCity ?loc
}
ORDER BY ?University LIMIT 10
```

What is the correct syntax for returning the properties of a parent class?

Or is my approach entirely incorrect, and I should begin my query by searching for `EducationalInstitutions` where has property `University`?

I've attempted the latter, too, but find no luck:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?EducationalInstitution a dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution;
                           a dbpedia-owl:University.
   ?EducationalInstitution dbpedia-owl:locationCity ?City.
   }
ORDER BY ?University LIMIT 10
```

However, searching for a different field which belongs in University, not solely in EducationalInstitution, [this does work](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?EducationalInstitution%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aEducationalInstitution;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aUniversity.%0D%0A%20%20%20?EducationalInstitution%20dbpedia-owl%3adean%20?Dean.%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20?University%20LIMIT%2010):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?EducationalInstitution a dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution;
                           a dbpedia-owl:University.
   ?EducationalInstitution dbpedia-owl:dean ?Dean.
   }
ORDER BY ?University LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWL ontologies (what we're working with) aren't object oriented programming languages.  Properties don't belong to classes.  When we say that the domain of a property P is a class D, it means that when we see a triple on the property, e.g., X P Y, we can *infer* that X is a D.  That's all it means. When [the mapping page for University](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/University) says that locationCity is a property on University, I *think* that what it means is that the domain of locationCity is a superclass of University, so it wouldn't be inconsistent if a University has a locationCity.  I'm basing this on the results of the simple describe query `describe dbpedia-owl:locationCity`, which has [these results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=describe%20dbpedia-owl:locationCity&format=text/turtle&timeout=30000&debug=on) (note that the domain of locationCity is Organisation, and that Organisation is a superclass of University):

```
@prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dbpedia-owl:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix owl:    <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

dbpedia-owl:locationCity
    rdf:type    owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:domain dbpedia-owl:Organisation ;
    rdfs:range  dbpedia-owl:City ;
    rdfs:label  "locatie stad"@nl , "ville"@fr , "location city"@en ;
    rdfs:comment    "City the thing is located."@en .
```

In general, it's useful to see what's actually in the data, and base your queries on that.For instance,  you might look at the data that is defined for [Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute](http://dbpedia.org/page/Rensselaer_Polytechnic_Institute) and notice, for instance, that for the property 
`dbpedia-owl:city` it has the value `dbpedia:Troy,_New_York`.  If you want to select things that have type `dbpedia-owl:University` (i.e., have `dbpedia-owl:University` as a *value* of the `rdf:type` property) *and* their values for the `dbpedia-owl:city` property, you just ask for it:

```
select ?university ?city where {
  ?university rdf:type dbpedia-owl:University .
  ?university dbpedia-owl:city ?city .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?university%20?city%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?university%20rdf:type%20dbpedia-owl:University%20.%0D%0A%20%20?university%20dbpedia-owl:city%20?city%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

In SPARQL, you can use `a` as an abbreviation for `rdf:type`, and when you have multiple triples with the same subject, you can combine them with the `;` syntax, so we can make that query nicer looking as follows:

```
select ?university ?city where {
  ?university rdf:type dbpedia-owl:University ;
              dbpedia-owl:city ?city .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?university%20?city%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?university%20rdf:type%20dbpedia-owl:University%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:city%20?city%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Notice that I'm using the `dbpedia-owl:` properties here.  These come from the DBpedia ontology, and that has much cleaner data than the raw infobox data (the `dbpprop:` properties).  I've discussed this a bit more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014265/1281433) to [Why there is differences in the number of links connected to the same property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16977418/1281433).

Basing your queries on the data is actually pretty important.  While the mappings wiki, as you saw, mentioned the locationCity property, it's not actually used on any Universities in the data:

```
select ?university ?city where {
  ?university a dbpedia-owl:University ;
              dbpedia-owl:locationCity ?city .
}
```

[SPARQL results (no results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?university%20?city%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?university%20a%20dbpedia-owl:University%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:locationCity%20?city%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can even use SPARQL to find out what `dbpedia-owl:` properties have been used to relate Universities to Cities:

```
select distinct ?p where {
  ?university a dbpedia-owl:University ;
              ?p [ a dbpedia-owl:City ] .
  filter strstarts(str(?p),str(dbpedia-owl:))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?p%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?university%20a%20dbpedia-owl:University%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?p%20%5B%20a%20dbpedia-owl:City%20%5D%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28?p%29,str%28dbpedia-owl:%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
p
-------------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/city
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/campus
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/state
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/affiliation
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/province
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/president
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type
```

It's not immediately clear why some of those would be used (e.g., president, or type), but I can see where some might be used, if perhaps incorrectly (e.g., state, or province).

Comment: That resolves all my questions, even some I didn't know I had, and is a remarkably good introduction to how I need to change my thinking to get a better handle on using sparql.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

The answer seems to be the property is location, not locationCity.

Comment: It's not clear how this is an answer without some more context.  Can you expand on this?