# Difference DBpedia ontology and DBpedia mapping

Tags: ontology, dbpedia, linked-data

I'm trying to do some date mining with DBpedia. Now I have a dataset with properties of DBpedia ontology and DBpedia mapping and I'm not sure about the difference between those two.

What is the difference between DBpedia ontology and DBpedia mapping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is differences in the number of links connected to the same property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977418/why-there-is-differences-in-the-number-of-links-connected-to-the-same-property);  the name of the question isn't very helpful, but [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014265/1281433) describes the difference between the raw infobox data and the ontology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, DBpedia a very valuable resource for the semantic web community, but compared to Wikipedia it is quite small. Also, due to contribution of various people to Wikipedia, the infobox information is no harmonised. Therefore, a mapping language has been created to define synonymy between infobox relations and DBpedia properties.

> One of the challenges in extracting information from Wikipedia is that the same concepts can be expressed using different parameters in infobox and other templates, such as `|birthplace=` and `|placeofbirth=`. Because of this, queries about where people were born would have to search for both of these properties in order to get more complete results. As a result, the **DBpedia Mapping Language** has been developed to help in mapping these properties to an ontology while reducing the number of synonyms. Due to the large diversity of infoboxes and properties in use on Wikipedia, the process of developing and improving these mappings has been opened to public contributions.